# background-image url not found inside jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, background-image, onerror

I'm using jQuery and loading data from a SQL call inside a PHP script.  The data loads fine but I need some error checking as sometimes the image url is valid other times not.

My jQuery ajax call looks like:

```
    $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load properties.
      type: "GET",
      url: "code/phpscript.php",
      data: datastring,
      dataType: "json",   //expect json to be returned
      cache: false,
      success: function(response){
         var arr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
         var htmlspecial = " ";
         for(var i =0; i < arr.length; i++){
              ...code
              // sometimes these image urls work sometimes not
              var image = "";
              if (arr[i]['image1'] == "" || arr[i]["image1"].indexOf("noimage") >= 0 || arr[i]["image1"].indexOf("no-image")  >= 0 ) {            
               image = "";
            } else {
               image = "https://images.weserv.nl/?url="+arr[i]['image1'].substr(arr[i]['image1'].indexOf("//"));
            }
             htmlspecial += '<div class="col m6 classname"><div class="backgroundPic" style="background: url(' + image + '), url();">   ... more html
         }
      });
```

At the moment the console is throwing 404 errors, I need to stop these error messages.  I dont want to replace the image with no-image.png because the default background is dark blue.

What I have tried?

I have tried onerror but this does not work on style="background..etc".
I have also tried:

```
    $(".backgroundPic").on("error",function() { 
      $('body').css({
        "background-image": 'url()'

      });alert("error");
    }).on("load",function() {
      $('body').css({
        "background-image": 'url(' + image + ')'
      });
    }).attr("src",image);
```

This does not work inside an ajax call.

Comment: There is no error on element for background image 404. You would need to create an image element and  pass url to it and check error on that image element. Also `, url()` in your `style` is invalid

Comment: ok thanks @charlietfl